# Density function of a random variable in terms of another random variable

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

> Random variable X has density function f and Y = g(X) for some differentiable function g such that
>   g′(x) > 0 for all x. What is the density function of Y?

I started with $$\int_0^{\infty}g(X)dx$$
But it doesn't get me anywhere.
So I wanted to use the info given in the question that g`(x) exists.
So $X= g^{-1}(Y)$ exists.
I am not sure how to proceed further.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try starting with the definition of the cumulative density function: $$\mathrm{CDF}(X) = \int_{X < x} f(x) \operatorname{d}x,$$ then do a change of variables in the integral $y = g(x)$. Note that $g'(x) > 0$ ensures that $g$ is monotonic, and therefore invertable.